# Counting Process Conditioned on Random Rate

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Having some trouble figuring out this problem. Say you have a counting process $N_t$ where the rate is a random variable $\Lambda$ which is exponentially distributed with rate $\alpha$. I'm trying to find the unconditional PMF of $N_t$, as well as the conditional expectation of $\Lambda$ given $N_t$ and the first $n$ arrival times (i.e. $E(\Lambda | N_t = n, S_1 = s_1, ... , S_n = s_n)$). I'm hoping this would maybe be easier to figure out once I'm able to figure out the unconditional PMF of $N_t$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For the unconditional PMF of $N_t$, did you try using something like $\mathbb{P}(N_t = n) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(N_t=n\mid \Lambda = x)f_{\Lambda}(x)\, dx$?

Comment: I'm trying that now and think I'm getting closer. Is it true that the distribution of N given Λ is just a Poisson process with rate x?

Comment: Almost! For $N_t$, it should be rate $tx$. (E.g. $N_3$ would be Poisson with rate $3x$.)